# Count days and duration of events in a list of dates

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have two columns, one is a list of dates, the other is a list of durations. These form part of an enquiry log that is continuously being added to, so there is no well-defined range.

I would like to count the number of entries which are Mondays (and etc.) and also the total duration of enquiries on Mondays (and etc.).

I have a rough solution for the counting, using sumproduct and weekday, and just defining the range as well over what I expect it to have to cope with (I can't use A:A because of header rows, which is frustrating) but I can't figure out the second part at all.

Comment: Convert the range to a table so you can just reference the table columns, e.g. `Table1[Header Name]`

Comment: Try using format as table to convert/define your current table to data as a table in excel. It does much more than just make it look pretty. You can reference columns by their given title e.g =sum(table1[SALES]) and so it doesn't matter if you have 100 sales entries or 10000  it will work.  I also allows you to create a formula column in the table that will be automatically replicated on each new row.  If you're still not sure what I'm talking about, select all your data with the headings and click the Format as table button on the Home menu and select a style.

Comment: Regardless of header rows, **never** use A:A in [SUMPRODUCT](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/sumproduct-function-4e0bffa7-4291-4635-a61f-6aaa9399e7ff).

Comment: If you go the **structured table** route, see [Using structured references with Excel tables](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Using-structured-references-with-Excel-tables-F5ED2452-2337-4F71-BED3-C8AE6D2B276E) for more information..

Answer (score 2):

I go with Gordon's suggestion of making it a dynamic list (you just select range and press Ctrl+t and it's done - all your formats and formulas will extend automatically with new data lines)

I don't know how big that table gets but conditional sumproduct gets very heavy very quickly.

I suggest:

1. convert into table : select range, press Ctrl+T, tick "Table Has Headers" in pop-up dialog.
2. Add a column to the table with the WEEKDAY(Table1[Date] as formula (you can format it as "ddd" in Custom formats to display as "Mon" etc
3. Add a Pivot table next to the table and pivot it by Weekday

You get your totals with much more flexibility than sumproducting it in a cell as a one off. If you add lines to the bottom of the table, formula will extend itself, and so will pivot table's source range. You'll need to refresh pivot table - but that's all.

[image: output]

Answer (score 1):

You're correct in that you can use `SUMPRODUCT`.

Suppose your table looks as follows (and is a table not a range):

```
Date        |  Duration
20/02/2017  |  5        '<--- Monday
21/02/2017  |  5
22/02/2017  |  5
23/02/2017  |  5
24/02/2017  |  5
25/02/2017  |  5
26/02/2017  |  5
27/02/2017  |  5        '<--- Monday
28/02/2017  |  5
```

Lets call the table `Table1`.

To `COUNT` the Mondays you could use:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((WEEKDAY(Table1[Date],2)=1)*1)
```

To `SUM` the durations that fall on a Monday you could use:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((WEEKDAY(Table1[Date],2)=1)*(Table1[Duration]))
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `a$2:index(a:a, match(1e99, a:a))` to define the range of dates.

To count Mondays,

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(WEEKDAY(A$2:INDEX(A:A, MATCH(1E+99,A:A )))= 2))
```

To sum the durations on Mondays,

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(WEEKDAY(A$2:INDEX(A:A, MATCH(1E+99,A:A )))= 2), B$2:INDEX(B:B, MATCH(1E+99,A:A )))
```

Example:

[image]

Alternately, define named dynamic ranges with a similar formula.

Comment: This works great, thanks so much. What does 1E+99 mean please?

Comment: `1e+99` is a very large number; literally a **1** followed by 99 zeroes. It is used because it will never be reached. In this way, [MATCH](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/match-function-0600e189-9f3c-4e4f-98c1-943a0eb427ca) returns the last row with a number/date. If you were looking for the last text value, you would use `"zzz"`.

Comment: Thank you, that's really useful, and has allowed me to add additional criteria that are text based. I can now count enquires by month and origin, very good.